# Reloading Page Shows 404 error message after Enabling AngularJS HTML5 mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, .htaccess

I have enabled HTML5 mode for my app. I have put the following code for the configuration, as shown below

```
return app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$locationProvider.hashPrefix = '!';

$routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: '/pages/index.html',
    controller: 'indexCtrl'
});
$routeProvider.when('/about',{
    templateUrl: '/pages/about.html',
    controller: 'AboutCtrl'
});
```

Also I have done some changes in .htaccess file as below

```
RewriteEngine On 
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#/$1 [L]
```

Also I have done some changes in index.html also liek

```
<base href="/">
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set a

```
<base href="">
```

tag inside your head tag?

[$location Relative Links](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#relative-links)

Comment: Yes i did set this  also